# How to get the value of selected radio button in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the html part:

```
<input class="demo" radio-value="yes" name="Radios" id="sample1" value="" type="radio"> 
<input class="demo" radio-value="yes" name="Radios" id="sample2" value="" type="radio"> 
<input class="demo" radio-value="yes" name="Radios" id="sample3" value="" type="radio"> 
<input class="demo" radio-value="yes" name="Radios" id="sample4" value="" type="radio">
```

How can I know which radio button the user is selected and how can I know the value of selected radio button.

I want to get the "radio-value" of the selected button. Because, I will be using value for json input..

How can I do that??

Comment: they all can't have the same ID value. ID is unique by definition where class does not have to be.

Comment: Why not setting the `value` attribute instead of using invalid `radio-value` attribute?

Comment: Name is also a unique, for radio groups you should use Radios[]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, all of your radio buttons have the same id - this is illegal and can cause unexpected behavior. Provided this is fixed, you can do something like this:

```
var selectedValue = $("input.demo:checked").val();
```

and for `radio-value`:

```
var selectedRadioValue = $("input.demo:checked").attr("radio-value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:selected` with class selector to get the selected radio button. You should give **unique** ids to html elements. Also the value of all the radio button is empty string you may need to assign some values to them

```
$('.demo:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.demo:selected').val(); // class is demo
```

This would do the trick!

But you need to remove the `id` that is similar among all the elements. You should change their value such as `sample1`, `sample2` etc. Then you can get the value, and the id.

Comment: Let's hope that `demo` is only used as a class of the radio buttons that he is targeting.